# How to restrict access to REST API used by Angular application

Tags: angular, api, security

I have an Angular application that doesn't require a login.  It's a site to sign-up for a real-world service and it needs to be open to anyone to access.  As part of the sign-up process, it needs to call REST APIs.  If this was a server-side application I'd use a secret key(s) to guard access to the REST APIs.  But since it's Angular it's client-side and there are many ways to monitor the network activity to grab the secret key.  Once someone has the secret key, they could call the REST API from anywhere (like Postman).
Is there a way to make sure that the REST APIs are only called from the Angular application?  I've read about having an authentication service that takes login credentials and provides a session token (that could then be passed with the REST API calls).  But in my case, there’s no login done by the user.  The application could have its own login credentials to pass to the authentication service but then the authentication service call becomes the weak point with the application's login credentials open to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - not really.

Any frontend code (which ends up downloaded and run in the user's browser) is able to be examined by a user. You can encrypt secrets, try to obfuscate your encryption.. but at the end of the day, the methods you call to do that can still be read and used by any savvy user.

There's a two-pronged approach to *reducing* the ease with which end users could spam your API:

1. **[Backend]** Implement rate limiting, IP tracking, User Agent verification, etc. Anyone can spoof a UA, but someone has to go out of their way to alter it. Rate limiting by IP means an attacker couldn't hit a specific route more than X times over Y minutes. (Additionally, depending on your app, certain DNS/CDN providers can provide this service at their end - think Cloudflare).
2. **[Frontend]** Security through obfuscation, as mentioned. You could use a custom HTTP header appended to your requests with a secret key that's generated on the front end and verified on the back end. Easily intercepted and read, but it's a start. Use some custom hashing algorithm to encrypt your key. For a public-facing endpoint, your best bet is just to put as many obstacles as possible in an attacker's way. I saw you mention a session token, which absolutely would work (as a sort of rate limiting tool) - but anyone using Postman or similar could grab one and use that for an attack (for whatever time period your token is valid).